# How to access web API on client machine

Tags: asp.net-web-api, iis-10

I have hosted web API on Windows server 2012 .  I set the binding like port and ipaddress.

After configuration, I browse the API and it's working fine.

Now I wanted to access my configured API from other machines.

What configuration I need to do in my web config.

I am beginner on deployment stuff. Please help me out on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: refer this : https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking and ask your question properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to set Access-Control-Allow-Origin headers. Specifically for JSON:

```
[AllowCrossSiteJson]
public ActionResult YourMethod()
{
    return Json("Works better?");
}
```

Or for a whole controller:

```
[AllowCrossSiteJson]
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
```

You can also edit your web.config to include:

```
<httpProtocol>
   <customHeaders>
      <clear />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
   </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors